# How to fix Reflected XSS vulnerability in my node.js application

Tags: node.js, express, xss, checkmarx, secure-coding

I am writing the backend of an application using express in node.js. Checkmarx highlights this issue: Improper Neutralization of Input During Web Page Generation

The line of code highlighted: `const token = req.params.company2tftoken;`

What can I do to fix this? Any article will also work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a quick intro to what [Reflected XSS](https://portswigger.net/web-security/cross-site-scripting/reflected) is and what harm this vulnerability can do to your Node app

In general, one of the ways to prevent XSS is to output encode/escape. Depending on the contextual output (URL, javascript, HTML) where req.params.company2tftoken might end, will determine what function to use. I'm assuming URL so you may try with URL encoding using the [querystring.escape](https://nodejs.org/api/querystring.html#querystring_querystring_escape_str) method

```
const token = querystring.escape(req.params.company2tftoken);
```

Comment: Hi @Roman , I am also getting this checkmarx vulnerability about reflected XSS whenever I am using request.session in the code, any solution for that?

Comment: Hi @SarikaRajput the solution would be the same. HTML, javascript or URL encode the session value

Comment: I am also getting this checkmarx vulnerability about reflected XSS whenever I am using request.param in the code, any solution for that?

Comment: Finally this resolved CheckMarx issue. Don't know why hahaa :) thanks for the recommendation man!

Comment: @AsiriH. glad that I could be of help :) feel free to mark this answer as useful

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [xss-filters](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xss-filters) npm library

const xssFilters = require('xss-filters');

const token = xssFilters.inHTMLData(req.params.company2tftoken);