# How to resolve Reflected XSS vulnerability for querystring in node.js

Tags: node.js, xss

I was trying to solve it using inHTMLData() of xss-filters library like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72396137/5650332). But it did not work as `req.query` is an object

```
function data(req, res) {

  fetchData(req.params.uniqueId, req.params.name, req.query) // query has multiple data
    .then((result) => {res.json(result)})
    .catch((error) => res.json(error));
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using  [xss-filters](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xss-filters) npm library

1. First stringify query string
2. Use inHTMLData of xss-filters
3. Use JSON.parse

const xssFilters = require('xss-filters');

function data(req, res) {

```
  const uniqueId = xssFilters.inHTMLData(req.params.uniqueId);
  
  const name = xssFilters.inHTMLData(req.params.name);
  
  const query = xssFilters.inHTMLData(JSON.stringify(req.query));

  fetchData(uniqueId, name, JSON.parse(query)) // query has multiple data
    
    .then((result) => {res.json(result)})

    .catch((error) => res.json(error));
};
```